# 2 Foreign key fields referencing the same django model leads to migration errors

Tags: python, mysql, django, foreign-keys, migration

I have a model named `Profile` (with various fields), and another model `Trans`.
The model `Trans` is as follows (both models are in `accounts` app):

```
class Trans(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receiver')
    #...
```

Created many instances (in views) using:

```
t = Trans.objects.create(sender_id=profile.pk, receiver_id=prof.pk, ...)
t.save()
```

Where `profile.pk` and `prof.pk` are primary keys two different Profile objects (sender and receiver).

Migrating the app leads to this error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '2' for key 'accounts_trans_receiver_id_592a7105_uniq'")

I checked the table structure of `accounts_trans` in MySQL server, and I found that `sender_id` is taken as a `MUL` key which means "Multiple records can have the same sender(profile)". While the receiver is not assigned as a `MUL` key and this I guess is why the migration is not working! I'm not able to alter the `receiver_id` field to `MUL` in MySQL database.

Can anyone help solve this issue? Thank you in advance.